# inserting new columns by splitting each column and iterating for many columns in python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Here I have an example dataframe:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': ['alex','bob','jack'],
        'age': ["0,26,4","1,25,4","5,30,2"],
        'job': ["x,abc,0","y,xyz,1","z,pqr,2"],
        'gender': ["0,1","0,1","0,1"]            
    })
```

I want to first split column **dfx['age']**  and insert 3 separate columns  for it, one for each substring in age value, naming them **dfx['age1']**,**dfx['age2']**,**dfx['age3']** . I used following code for this:

```
dfx = dfx.assign(**{'age1':(dfx['age'].str.split(',', expand = True)[0]),\
         'age2':(dfx['age'].str.split(',', expand = True)[1]),\
         'age3':(dfx['age'].str.split(',', expand = True)[2])})
dfx = dfx[['name', 'age','age1', 'age2', 'age3', 'job', 'gender']]
dfx
```

So far so good!

Now, I want to repeat the same operations to other columns **job**  and **gender**.

**Desired Output**

```
   name     age age1 age2 age3      job job1 job2 job3 gender gender1 gender2
0  alex  0,26,4    0   26    4  x,abc,0    x  abc    0    0,1       0       1
1   bob  1,25,4    1   25    4  y,xyz,1    y  xyz    1    0,1       0       1
2  jack  5,30,2    5   30    2  z,pqr,2    z  pqr    2    0,1       0       1
```

I have no problem doing it individually for small data frame like this. But, the actual datafile has many such columns. I need **iterations**.

I found difficulty in iteration over columns, and naming the individual columns.

I would be very glad to have better solution for it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for splitting columns defined in list for list of DataFrames, add filtered columns and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with sorting columns names, then prepend not matched columns by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
cols = ['age','job','gender']

L = [dfx[x].str.split(',',expand=True).rename(columns=lambda y: f'{x}{y+1}') for x in cols]

df1 = dfx[dfx.columns.difference(cols)]
df = df1.join(pd.concat([dfx[cols]] + L, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
   name     age age1 age2 age3 gender gender1 gender2      job job1 job2 job3
0  alex  0,26,4    0   26    4    0,1       0       1  x,abc,0    x  abc    0
1   bob  1,25,4    1   25    4    0,1       0       1  y,xyz,1    y  xyz    1
2  jack  5,30,2    5   30    2    0,1       0       1  z,pqr,2    z  pqr    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @jezrael for your answer. Being inspired by the use of 'f-string' I have solved the problem using iteration as follows:

```
for col in dfx.columns[1:]:
for i in range(len(dfx[col][0].split(','))):
    dfx[f'{col}{i+1}'] = (dfx[col].str.split(',', expand = True)[i])
    
dfx = dfx[['name', 'age','age1', 'age2', 'age3', 'job','job1', 'job2','job3', 'gender' 
, 'gender1', 'gender2']]
    
dfx
```